# iOS 16 Image() in LockScreen Widget

Tags: widgetkit, ios16

I want to create lockscreen widget to display a single image (company logo). I have the basic setup in latest beta Xcode and iPhone 12 Pro Max also latest iOS 16 Beta. Here is code:

```
struct ZKLogoEntryView : View {
var entry: Provider.Entry

    var body: some View {
        Image("logoW")
        .resizable()
        .scaledToFit()
    }
}
```

It is working in canvas, displaying company logo, but doesn't work on device. See screenshots:
[Xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mH5q2.png) and [iPhone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nuIU.jpg)

So, am I doing this correct? Maybe Image() not even working in lockscreen widgets? Any other ways to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Everything was correct! The problem was in image parameters! I had to use photoshop to create image with correct size, color, dpi, format. You can find all that specs in apple developer documents. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please add a link to the Apple Docs you used to find the correct size/color/dpi/format.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In my case problem was from a misunderstanding:
The assets of my main target are different from my widget's target. I added an image to my widget's assets, then it loaded.